# Kruskal Algorithm proof

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, algorithms, trees, discrete-optimization

I was reading the proof of Kruskal Algorithm [Reference](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_Algorithm_produces_Minimum_Spanning_Tree).

What I am not understanding is why we assume that Kruskal always chooses the smallest edges? Maybe it did not choose one of the smallest edges because it could form a cycle? So in the proof here (and actually in many other ones)[Reference](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_Algorithm_produces_Minimum_Spanning_Tree), at the end of the proof, they conclude that $w(e_i) = w(e_0)$ since Kruskal chose $e_i$  which implies $w(e_i) \leq w(e_0)$, but maybe Kruskal didn't choose $e_0$ because it could form a cycle even though $w(e_0) \leq w(e_i)$?

Comment: The algorithm, by definition, chooses the smallest edge that does not form a cycle with any of the previously chosen edges.

Comment: Yes, I know but why in the proof, we say that $w(e_i) \leq w(e_0)$. Maybe it is not the case.

Comment: Thank you for quickly clarifying your question I understand now what you are asking I think.

Comment: For more clarity, here is my intuition behind the question:  For example, we have a set of edges with the following values: 1,2,3,4,5,6,20,21. Let's say the algorithm will choose 1 but after choosing 1, it saw it cannot choose 2,3,4,5,6 (it is exagerated) because they cause a cycle, so, it will choose 20,21. However, if we started by the edge 4, we could choose 5,6. I know this example is not applicable, but the idea is the following: maybe choosing a smaller edge at an earlier stage would have a negative impact at later stage

Comment: I answered your question and you do not seem to take a look at my answer

Comment: I apologize for this misunderstanding but I saw your answer but until now I haven't understood it. I need some time to grasp the correctness of this algorithm.

Comment: What didn't you understand about my answer?

Comment: This part:with strict smaller weight than $e_i$  which contradict the definition of $e_i$
.

Comment: After several readings, I read a proof based on cut property which I found it logical compared to the other ones: 
https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr07/cos226/lectures/mst

What I understood at the end is that the second property of the algorithm (choosign an edge that does not form a cycle) plays an essential part in making this greedy algorithm an optimal one

Answer (score 0):

If $w(e_0)< w(e_i)$ and $e_0$ was not chosen then it means that it created a cycle with a subtree of $T$. This means that you will find an edge in $T$ that is not in $T_0$ and with strict smaller weight than $e_i$ which contradict the definition of $e_i$.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is, you've made a forest $F$ out of your chosen edges.

By induction assume there exists $T$ a minimum spanning tree containing those edges and none of the rejected edges.

Then the algorithm chooses $e_1$ ($e_i$ in your link).

If $e_1$ is in $T$ then the inductive conclusion is established.

Otherwise, $T + e_1$ contains a cycle $C$.

$C$ contains an edge $e_2$ ($e_0$ in your link), distinct from $e_1$, not in $F$.  Because otherwise $F+e_1$ would have a cycle.

$e_2$ cannot be smaller than $e_1$, because it would have been previously chosen by the algorithm.  I think this is the part you are asking about.  Adding $e_2$ to $F$ can't form a cycle because $T$ is a supergraph of $F$ and $T$ without $e_1$ doesn't form a cycle.

$e_2$ cannot be larger than $e_1$, because then $T + e_1 - e_2$ is a smaller spanning tree than $T$, violating the induction assumption.

So $T + e_1 - e_2$ is a minimum spanning tree containing $F+e_1$ and the inductive conclusion is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But my intuition say, maybe in the future while building the MST we cannot choose an edge because it could form a cycle and the next small edge is very big so it could transform the MST into a non MST. To clarify my point here is an example:

Comment: I don't know if this example could apply but I am stating it just to explain my idea: For example, we have a set of edges with the following values: 1,2,3,4,5,6,20,21. Let's say the algorithm will choose 1 but after choosing 1, it saw it cannot choose 2,3,4,5,6 (it is exagerated) because they cause a cycle, so, it will choose 20,21. However, if we started by the edge 4, we could choose 5,6. I know this example is not applicable, but the idea is the following: maybe choosing a smaller edge at an earlier stage would have a negative impact at later stage

Answer (score 0):

In the linked proof $T$ is a spanning tree produced by Kruskal's algorithm and $T_0$ is a minimum spanning tree. Also $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_{i-1}$ are all edges of both $T$ and $T_0$, and $e_i$ is an edge of $T$ but not one of $T_0$.

The edge $e_0$ is chosen to be an edge of the cycle $C$ in $G_0$, but not an edge of $T$. The edges of $G_0$ are the edges of $T_0$ together with $e_i$, which is an edge of $T$, so $e_0$ must be an edge of $T_0$.

Hence $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_{i-1}$ and $e_0$ are all edges of the tree $T_0$ and trees don't contain cycles, so in Kruskal's algorithm choosing $e_0$ rather than $e_i$ as the next edge would not make a cycle.